# Commit WPF datagrid row when tab is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am using WPF microsoft technology in my project.
I have a datagrid that binds with a viewmodel property of datatype ICollectionViewLiveShaping.
I want to commit datagrid row when tab is pressed and the row at the bottom for adding items will be automatically focused.
This is automatically achieved when I pressed enter key.
I have to do the same when tab is pressed.

I will be very thankful, if someone helps me on this.

Comment: Do you have some code to show what you have done so far?

Comment: Does it matter where the focus is at the time of pressing the tab key? I assume you'd still want to be able to move the focus from cell to cell? Or do you want to save the changes on every focus change?

Comment: You can use the "CellEditEnding" event to save your changes, it gets called when you tab from one cell to the other

Comment: How about you simply 'fake' an enter click when tab is pressed by implementing an own KeyDown event which calls the default enter-KeyDownEvent, when the Key was tab?  private void DataGrid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
    {
      DataGrid_KeyDown(sender, new KeyEventArgs(e.KeyboardDevice, e.InputSource, e.Timestamp, Key.Return));
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna do it in MVVM pattern.
then bound Keyboard keyhandler to viewmodel.
and in case of TAB key use below code.

```
List<string> yourCollection = new List<string>(); // your view model collection
ICollectionView yourCollectionView = new CollectionViewSource { Source = yourCollection }.View;
ListCollectionView listCollectionView = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(yourCollectionView);
if (listCollectionView != null)
{
    if (listCollectionView.IsAddingNew)
    {
        listCollectionView.CommitNew();
    }
    if (listCollectionView.IsEditingItem)
    {
        listCollectionView.CommitEdit();
    }
}
```

if you want to do it in view itself then use below code.

```
this.ItemsGrid.CommitEdit(); 
this.ItemsGrid.CancelEdit();
```

Please vote in case this help you.

Comment: My problem statement is: 
After commit the row, one blank row will generate, and that row will be selected automatically and cursor would be on the 2nd column of the the row.